# flexDirection: "row" not working react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am developing a react-native application. One of the app screens contains a  list of albums. I have divided each album container into components which are Card and CardSection.

A Card can contain many CardSections. The CardSection will contain an image and 2 Text titles. The problem I am facing is with the positioning of the content in the CardSection as `flexDirection:'row'` is not working.

Here is the CardSection.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image} from 'react-native';

import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from "./CardSection";
const AlbumDetail = ({album}) => {

// destructing the props
const {title, artist, thumbnail_image} = album;
return (
    <Card>
        <CardSection>

            <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                <Image style={styles.thumbnailStyle} source={{uri: thumbnail_image}} />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.headerContentStyle} >
                <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
                <Text>{artist}</Text>
            </View>

        </CardSection>
    </Card>
);
};

const styles = {
  headerContentStyle: {
     flexDirection: 'column',
     justifyContent: 'space-around'
},
headerTextStyle:{
    fontSize:18
},
thumbnailStyle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50
},
thumbnailContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    marginRight: 10
}
};

export default AlbumDetail;
```

Here is the CardSection.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {View} from 'react-native';


const CardSection = (props) => {
return (
    <View styles={styles.containerStyle}>
        {props.children}
    </View>
);

};

const styles = {
 containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
}
};
export default CardSection;
```

The resultant should that the Image placed towards the left and on the right side of the image there will be 2 Text titles and their flexDirection will be `column`

[image: ExpectedResult]
[image: Issue]

Comment: The best way to debug is install react-devtools and select show inspector so it will help you solve this. For me everything looks good.

Comment: Yeah, everything is good, but I don't know why it's not working. Btw Thanks, I will installed it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`<View styles={styles.containerStyle}>` you have typo, it is `styles`, the prop should be `style`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didnt work. Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/k3w89c

Comment: The issue, as far I think is in the CardSection.js. The flexDirection: 'column' will remain column as this is for the text titles. The flexDirection: 'row' in the CardSection.js is not working. 
`containerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        position: 'relative'
    }`

Comment: Spot on man.... spot on... its as though you looked into my code...

Comment: This was my issue as well T__T

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
headerContentStyle: {
     flexDirection: 'row',
     justifyContent: 'space-around'
}
```

instead of

```
headerContentStyle: {
     flexDirection: 'column',
     justifyContent: 'space-around'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didnt work. Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/k3w89c

Comment: The issue, as far I think is in the CardSection.js. The flexDirection: 'column' will remain column as this is for the text titles. The flexDirection: 'row' in the CardSection.js is not working. 
`containerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        position: 'relative'
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use card containerStyle props in CardSection.js file.
there you should have to use flexDirection :'row' .
Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where `flexDirection: 'row'` was not working in one of my components that I was importing in `App.js`.

What was causing this was the `alignItems: 'center'` in the stylesheet for the main container in my `App.js` file.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this.

```
import {  TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably figured it by now, but I just faced a similar issue

you added `styles={styles.containerStyle}`,whereas it should be `style={styles.containerStyle}`

you added an extra ***s*** on the style